# How to generate csv file with default UTF-8 encoding using php

Tags: mysql, csv, utf-8, character-encoding

By fetching data from mysql table i am generating csv file and uploading to some ftp folder. But other person using this csv file from ftp side says that it is in ANSI encoding. How can i change that to UTF-8 encoding? For this I am using the below code.

```
   header('Content-Encoding: utf-8');
   header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    $fh1 = fopen($current_csv_name, 'w+');
    foreach($csv_data as $curl_response)
    {
        fputs($fh1, implode($curl_response, ';')."\n");
    }
    fclose($fh1);
```

When i download the file and open in notepad and click on save as it is always showing Encoding as ASNI. Where i am doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you explicitly force an application (Notepad++ or whatever) to treat the file as UTF-8, does the content appear correctly? Then it's UTF-8. If the content consists only of basic ASCII characters then UTF-8 is indistinguishable from virtually all other encodings, and Notepad et al. are merely guessing incorrectly.

Comment: Why is this tagged mysql?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need to add the BOM (Byte order Mark) at the beginning of the file, otherwise, the filesystem will always assume your charset to be ANSI by default. Try doing this:

```
header('Content-Encoding: utf-8');
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
$fh1 = fopen($current_csv_name, 'w+');

$bom = chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF);
fputs($fh1, $bom);

foreach($csv_data as $curl_response)
{
    fputs($fh1, implode($curl_response, ';')."\n");
}
fclose($fh1);
```

Comment: This seems to be the case. I tried with and without the BOM, but the CSV only showed utf-8 characters with it included.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is UTF in your DB, then you need to modify how your produce the document.

In my code I replace a bare echo with a modified one using iconv:

```
// echo $csv;
echo iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-2", $csv);
```